# How to create Azure DevOps Release Task for .NET Core 3.0 Self-contained app

Tags: azure-devops-extensions

I have a .NET Core 3.0 self-contained CLI app and I would like to make it available in Azure DevOps Release Pipelines Task. I wish to have task like "Use MyApp". Something like "Use Node" or "Use .NET Core" style. The task flow would be like these:

Task1: Use MyApp

1. Download EXE file from github
2. Set PATH to include the location of EXE

Task2: Run MyApp

1. Run MyApp with args from Az DevOps GUI

I have been going through many articles but I have yet to see any EXE file example. This is the closest I can get but it was NPM package. Do I need to package my CLI app into NPM, if thats even possible? https://devkimchi.com/2019/07/03/building-azure-devops-extension-on-azure-devops-2/

Thanks for advise. //Ardi

Comment: Looks like I would have to implement the functionality of downloading the EXE file using typescript. Saw sample code here http://blog.majcica.com/2018/12/07/download-a-file-with-typescript/.

Comment: Your requirements of the task flow looks similar to [`Use Nuget task`](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/NuGetToolInstallerV1) and [`Nuget Command task`](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/NuGetCommandV2). Good news is that these two tasks are open source, you may get some help from them. And quick start about pipeline extension see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser%2Ctfs-2018-2).

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT thanks! You helped me at least where to look and it seems I can copy the `UseDotNet` Task https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/UseDotNetV2

Comment: Glad to know it makes some help. And you can consider adding that as [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you've got this issue resolved.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT yes, I mashed up samples from UseNode and some other tasks. I finally get this to work, its soo cool :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After mashing-up various samples, I finaly made this to work. I still have chose Node+Typescript instead of Powershell.

Here's a code how I wrapped a self-contained app EXE file and made available as Azure Pipelines Task.

https://github.com/rdagumampan/yuniql-azure-pipelines-tasks

Comment: Hi friend, thanks for your sharing and please mark your reply as answer and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :)